# I am having trouble downloading the ADT Plugin using the URL provided

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

When I try to download the ADT Plugin in Eclispe using the URL provided https://d1-ss1.google.com/android/eclispe/ It comes back saying that it can't find this location.  I have tried using "http:" also and get the same error.

I have also tried downloading the plugin (ADT-8.0.0.zip) as directed.  When I try to configure the ADT Plugin (Window>preferences), Android is not listed in the left panel.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's `dl-ssl` (as in "down**load** secure sockets **layer**"), not `d1-ss1` - just copy/paste the URL from the instructions into Eclipse:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing